# custom action returns failure, but msi still returns 0

Tags: wix, custom-action

I'm attempting to modify some inherited code.  I have a custom action that was hardcoded to return success.  I have it run before LaunchConditions.  If there was a failure, it would set a value to be false, and that would force an error message.

```
    <Condition Message='The application cannot be installed while Office is open.'>
      <![CDATA[DEPENDENT_PROCESSES_CLOSED = "true"]]>
    </Condition>
```

I'm not sure how this stops the install.  Outside of the property declaration, I can't find any other references to DEPENDENT_PROCESSES_CLOSED.
Edit: Turns out a Condition in the product by definition stops the install

The main problem with this setup is the msi would always return 0.  I want the msi to return a failure code, 1603, if it fails.  I tried changing the custom action to return ActionResult.Failure if the dependent processes are running.  While this stops the install, and tells the user the install failed, this resulted in two problems.

1) The conditional message no longer shows.
2) The msi still returns 0.

What do I need to do to have the custom action's error code be returned by the msi?  How do I display the conditional message?